# jq - extract parent key values as comma separated values next to child elements

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to extract the ranges from the below JSON output,

```
{
    "zscaler.net": {
        "continent : EMEA": {
            "city : Amsterdam II": [
                {
                    "range": "165.225.240.0/23",
                    "vpn": "ams2-2-vpn.zscaler.net",
                    "gre": "165.225.240.12",
                    "hostname": "ams2-2.sme.zscaler.net",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                },
                {
                    "range": "147.161.132.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "52",
                    "longitude": "5"
                }
            ],
            "city : Brussels II": [
                {
                    "range": "147.161.156.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "50",
                    "longitude": "5"
                }
            ]
        },
        "continent : Americas": {
            "city : Atlanta II": [
                {
                    "range": "104.129.204.0/23",
                    "vpn": "atl2-vpn.zscaler.net",
                    "gre": "104.129.204.32",
                    "hostname": "atl2.sme.zscaler.net",
                    "latitude": "34",
                    "longitude": "-84"
                },
                {
                    "range": "136.226.2.0/23",
                    "vpn": "",
                    "gre": "104.129.204.32",
                    "hostname": "",
                    "latitude": "34",
                    "longitude": "-84"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Which I am successfully able to extract using the following command,

`.["zscaler.net"]["continent : EMEA"] | .[][].range`

What I am looking for is to try to get the parent continent and parent city of each range beside each other as comma separated,

`165.225.240.0/23, EMEA, Amsterdam II`

`147.161.132.0/23, EMEA, Amsterdam II`

`147.161.156.0/23, EMEA, Brussels II`

I am trying to achieve this completely in jq and bash.

Please help.

Comment: Do you need it for `"continent : EMEA"` or for all the cities?

Comment: There was an edit to the requirement, sorry about that. But I am looking to get the parent values of continent and city next to each of the ranges

Comment: Not sure, if that comment answered my question. do you need the above ouptut for Americas region as well or not?

Comment: Yes, it'll be for all regions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `to_entries` combined with [`sub()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#sub(regex;tostring)sub(regex;string;flags)) to clean the key, then use [`join(",")`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) (or [`@csv`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping)) to get the desired output:

```
.["zscaler.net"]["continent : EMEA"] 
    | to_entries[] 
    | .key as $k 
    | .value[] 
    | [ .range, ($k | sub("city : "; "" )) ] | join(", ")
```

---

1. First we target the correct object

   ```
   .["zscaler.net"]["continent : EMEA"]
   ```
2. Then we use [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to get the object key
3. Save the key: `.key as $k`
4. [*For each* (`[]`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D) item in `.value`
5. Create a new array, containing

   - The `.range` of the current object
   - The key (`$k`), but we use [`sub`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#sub(regex;tostring)sub(regex;string;flags)) to replace `city :`  with nothing (`""`)
6. [`join(", ")`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) back the array to a csv string

---

```json
"165.225.240.0/23, Amsterdam II"
"147.161.132.0/23, Amsterdam II"
"147.161.156.0/23, Brussels II"
```

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/kVQy2rgyB64)

---

If you'd like the output for each continent, so remove the hardcoded `["continent : EMEA"]`, it can be replaced with another `[]` to *loop* over them and get the following output:

```
.["zscaler.net"][] | to_entries[] | .key as $k | .value[] | [ .range, ($k | sub("city : "; "" )) ] | join(", ")
```

```
165.225.240.0/23, Amsterdam II
147.161.132.0/23, Amsterdam II
147.161.156.0/23, Brussels II
104.129.204.0/23, Atlanta II
136.226.2.0/23, Atlanta II
```

##### [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SsSyhtUCH-Z)

Comment: I belive that is the same as my output? Please add the desired output to your question

Comment: 165.225.240.0/23, EMEA, Amsterdam II

Comment: Also, I would really love a brief explanation of your command. I am still learning jq trying my best to get up there.

Comment: I've added a more details explanation

Comment: Also FYI - OP wants it for all regions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75983859/jq-extract-parent-key-values-as-comma-separated-values-next-to-child-elements#comment134014557_75983859

Comment: Added some explaining about replacing `["continent : EMEA"]` with another `[]` to loop over multiple regions

Comment: Something wrong with the output/explanation @deadshotpro?

Comment: @0stone0 Your response really helped. It was not the exact output I was looking for. However, I managed to whip up something of my own after going through your command and explanation. Thanks a heap for that!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution that matches the desired output from the question:

```
.["zscaler.net"] | to_entries[]
| (.key|ltrimstr("continent : ")) as $cont
| .value | to_entries[]
| "\(.value[].range), \($cont), \(.key|ltrimstr("city : "))"
```

Output:

```
165.225.240.0/23, EMEA, Amsterdam II
147.161.132.0/23, EMEA, Amsterdam II
147.161.156.0/23, EMEA, Brussels II
104.129.204.0/23, Americas, Atlanta II
136.226.2.0/23, Americas, Atlanta II
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it by using `tostream`.

The output of `tostream` will have all the *parents* and key for each value.  This stream can be filtered (`select`) for the `range` key and then the desired parts of the stream element can be extracted/formatted/output.

```
.["zscaler.net"] | tostream
| select(.[0][-1] == "range")
| [.[-1], .[0][0:2][]|split(":")[-1]]
| join(",")
```

Example output:

```
165.225.240.0/23, EMEA, Amsterdam II
147.161.132.0/23, EMEA, Amsterdam II
147.161.156.0/23, EMEA, Brussels II
104.129.204.0/23, Americas, Atlanta II
136.226.2.0/23, Americas, Atlanta II
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/d0xhGQMiRJf).

#### Solution Elaboration

The inspiration behind this solution was recognizing that all the desired output fields are contained in a single element of the stream output.  Understanding the pipeline might be easiest by seeing what happens after each stage.

Filter:

```
.["zscaler.net"] | tostream
```

[Result](https://jqplay.org/s/PouQf4LDuE1):

```
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",0,"range"],"165.225.240.0/23"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",0,"vpn"],"ams2-2-vpn.zscaler.net"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",0,"gre"],"165.225.240.12"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",0,"hostname"],"ams2-2.sme.zscaler.net"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",0,"latitude"],"52"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",0,"longitude"],"5"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",0,"longitude"]]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1,"range"],"147.161.132.0/23"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1,"vpn"],""]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1,"gre"],""]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1,"hostname"],""]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1,"latitude"],"52"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1,"longitude"],"5"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1,"longitude"]]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1]]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0,"range"],"147.161.156.0/23"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0,"vpn"],""]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0,"gre"],""]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0,"hostname"],""]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0,"latitude"],"50"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0,"longitude"],"5"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0,"longitude"]]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0]]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II"]]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",0,"range"],"104.129.204.0/23"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",0,"vpn"],"atl2-vpn.zscaler.net"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",0,"gre"],"104.129.204.32"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",0,"hostname"],"atl2.sme.zscaler.net"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",0,"latitude"],"34"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",0,"longitude"],"-84"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",0,"longitude"]]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1,"range"],"136.226.2.0/23"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1,"vpn"],""]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1,"gre"],"104.129.204.32"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1,"hostname"],""]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1,"latitude"],"34"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1,"longitude"],"-84"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1,"longitude"]]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1]]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II"]]
[["continent : Americas"]]
```

You can see in the result above that each line where the stream element's path (the first element of the array, which is an array) that ends with `"range"` has all the fields in the desired output.  `.[0][-1]` accesses the the last array element of the first array for each element of the result stream above.  The rest is just some filtering and formatting.

[Limit the pipeline data to just the *`"range"`* lines](https://jqplay.org/s/LgguLhoXTA1):

```
.["zscaler.net"] | tostream
| select(.[0][-1] == "range")
```

Result:

```
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",0,"range"],"165.225.240.0/23"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Amsterdam II",1,"range"],"147.161.132.0/23"]
[["continent : EMEA","city : Brussels II",0,"range"],"147.161.156.0/23"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",0,"range"],"104.129.204.0/23"]
[["continent : Americas","city : Atlanta II",1,"range"],"136.226.2.0/23"]
```

To use `join(",")` at the end to create the desired CSV, the data needs to be *"extracted"* and put in an array.

From the above result, the `"range"` value is accessed with `.[-1]`, i.e., the last element of the array.  The `"continent"` and the `"city"` are the first and second element of the array that is itself the first element of the overall array, i.e., `.[0][0:2]`.  Just the value needs to be extracted from these elements and this can be done with `split(":")`.  Since this needs to be done for each element, you can iterate each element with `.[0][0:2][]`.  Piping this into `split(":")` formats the output as desired.

[Filter](https://jqplay.org/s/Q_VRLVyIXJQ):

```
.["zscaler.net"] | tostream
| select(.[0][-1] == "range")
| [.[-1], .[0][0:2][]|split(":")[-1]]
```

Result:

```
["165.225.240.0/23"," EMEA"," Amsterdam II"]
["147.161.132.0/23"," EMEA"," Amsterdam II"]
["147.161.156.0/23"," EMEA"," Brussels II"]
["104.129.204.0/23"," Americas"," Atlanta II"]
["136.226.2.0/23"," Americas"," Atlanta II"]
```

All that's left is to format the output as CSV with `join(",")` as shown in the original solution above.

Comment: Woah! This is quite the shorthand. But it works like a charm. Could you explain what you've done?

Comment: @deadshotpro I extended my answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the needed fields like so `\(.first) \(.second)`:

```
jq -r '.["zscaler.net"]["continent : EMEA"] | .[][]|"\(.range), \(.latitude), \(.longitude)"'
```

Output:

```
165.225.240.0/23, 52, 5
147.161.132.0/23, 52, 5
147.161.156.0/23, 50, 5
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful and informative. 
Right now, there was an edit to the requirement, sorry about that. But I am looking to get the parent values of the continent and city next to each of the ranges.